# Function to test if a pivot field's subtotals are visible

Tags: excel, vba

I want a function that tells me if a pivot field's subtotals are visible. For example, in this pivot table both Region and Item have subtotals turned on...

[image]

... but only the Region subtotals are showing, which makes sense. I want a function that returns true if the passed field's subtotals are actually shown in the pivot table.

This function takes a pivot field as its argument and returns whether subtotals are turned on. It returns true for both Region and Item fields since they both have subtotals turned on:

```
Function PivotFieldSubtotalsOn(pvtField As Excel.PivotField) As Boolean
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 12
    If pvtField.Subtotals(i) = True Then
        PivotFieldSubtotalsOn = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Instead I want it to return False for Item in the situation above since Item subtotals aren't actually shown.

I thought about checking whether the Field name and the word "Total" appear in a cell in the pivot table, but subtotal labels can be changed. My best guess is to add a test whether a field `Position` is not the last one for its `Orientation`, since subtotals don't show up in that case.

Comment: **" My best guess is to add a test whether a field Position is not the last one for its Orientation, since subtotals don't show up in that case."** That looks to me like the answer to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

My answer also includes my default `Sub` for creating and updating `PivotTable`s (you can ignore or remove the parts you don't need).

The code below loops through all `PivotFields` in `PivotTable`, and checks if the current `PivotField.Name = "Region"`. The next step is to check if `PivotField.Subtotals(1) = True`.

So I modified your function a bit to fit the way it is being called and used from the `Sub`, but in your case, if you are checking just one field ("Region"), you can put the entire code inside the `Sub`, but I'm not sure what's your code final goal.

**Function PivotFieldSubtotalsOn Code**

```
Function PivotFieldSubtotalsOn(pvtField As Excel.PivotField) As Boolean

If pvtField.Subtotals(1) = True Then
    PivotFieldSubtotalsOn = True
Else
    PivotFieldSubtotalsOn = False
End If

End Function
```

**Sub AutoSetupPivot Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoSetupPivot()

Dim PivotSht            As Worksheet
Dim SrcData             As Range
Dim Lrow                As Long, LCol       As Long
Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable

' determine the data range you want for the pivot
With Worksheets("DATA")
    Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set SrcData = .Range("A1:" & .Cells(Lrow, LCol).Address(False, False))
End With

' set destination Sheet for Pivot Table
Set PivotSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PIVOT")

' set Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, SrcData)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = PivotSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' check if "PivotTable1" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then    
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable1" sheet, start from Cell A3
    Set PvtTbl = PivotSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PivotSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")   

     'Create the headings and row and column orientation
     'Sum and all other Pivot Table setting
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in "DATA" Sheet)
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If


' ****** THIS SECTION RELATED DIRECTLY TO YOUR POST ******
Dim PvtFld              As PivotField    
Dim PvtFldSubTotalsOn   As Boolean

' loop through all Pivot Fiels in PiVot Table
For Each PvtFld In PvtTbl.PivotFields

    ' check if Pivot Field Name is "Region"
    If PvtFld.Name = "Region" Then
        ' call your function
        PvtFldSubTotalsOn = PivotFieldSubtotalsOn(PvtFld)
        ' for debug only
        MsgBox "Pivot Field " & PvtFld.Name & " value is " & PvtFldSubTotalsOn
    End If
Next PvtFld

End Sub
```

---

### Option 2

If you prefer to "empower" your Function, you can do all the "looping" and `If`s inside the function, and just send the Name of the `PivotField` you want to check if `SubTotal` is on , by sending the `String` directly :

```
Function PivotFieldSubtotalsOn(pvtFieldName As String) As Boolean

Dim PvtFld              As PivotField

' loop through all Pivot Fiels in Pivot Table
For Each PvtFld In PvtTbl.PivotFields

    ' check if Pivot Field Name is "Region"
    If PvtFld.Name = pvtFieldName Then
        If PvtFld.Subtotals(1) = True Then
            PivotFieldSubtotalsOn = True
        Else
            PivotFieldSubtotalsOn = False
        End If

        Exit For
    End If
Next PvtFld

End Function
```

`Sub` Code (for testing this function):

```
' call the funtion and send the Field Name (as String)
PvtFldSubTotalsOn = PivotFieldSubtotalsOn("Region")

' for debug only
MsgBox "Pivot Filed Region value is " & PvtFldSubTotalsOn
```

Comment: Hi Shai. Thanks for responding. I edited the question to try to make it clearer. I don't want to test whether subtotals are turned on. I want to test whether they are actually visible in the pivot table. So, in my example both Region and Item have Subtotals turned on but they aren't showing for Item, since it's the rightmost field in the row. I want the function to return False for Item. As in the example, I'm passing a single pivot field to the function. I'm using this in a PivotSelect command that fails when I refer to a fields subtotals if they are turned on but not showing.

Comment: @DougGlancy  I'm trying to understand your scenario , but not able. What do u mean by item? Pivotfield.item ? Can you add also the part that you call this function ? Are u getting a run-time error ? What line ? I'm sorry for all these questions, but I'm trying to understand better

Comment: By Item, I mean the field called Item in the pivot table shown in the example. There is no runtime error. The function just doesn't do what I want, i.e., tell me if a pivot field's subtotals are actually visible. Again, in the example, both the Region and Item fields have subtotals turned on, but only Region's are visible. I want a function to return True only if they are visible. The function I showed only gets me partway there.